# Why does "cw" from middle of current word not move to beginning of next word like "w" or "dw"?

Tags: cursor-movement, normal-mode

#### Example scenario

I have this text consisting of two columns with different words of different lengths and alignments:

```
asdf     foo
bar   qwer
zzzzz   xx
```

Let's say I want to abbreviate the first column to a single character, insert a comma between the columns, and align the words.

I had imagined to do it like this:

- Place the cursor on the second character of the line:

  ```
    asdf     foo
     ^
  ```
- Type `cw, <ESC>` to get:

  ```
    a, foo
      ^
  ```
- Type `jh.` repeatedly to do the same action for all other lines:

  ```
    a, foo
    b, qwer
    z, xx
      ^
  ```

However, it does not work, because typing `cw` in this situation

```
asdf     foo
 ^
```

leads to

```
a    foo
 I
```

and not

```
afoo
 I
```

(where `I` means the cursor in insert mode).

#### Question

As I expect, typing only `w` in the same situation leads to

```
asdf     foo
         ^
```

and typing `dw` leads to

```
afoo
 ^
```

Why does `cw` behave differently and delete only until the *end of the current word* instead of the *beginning of the next word*, and if possible, how can I make it do what I expect or replace it with a different single movement command I'm currently not aware of?

`cw` is essentially the same as `ce` in this case.

I'm using Vim 8.1 and confirmed this behaviour with `vim -u NONE`.

Comment: `:h cw` also suggests workarounds that do not quite work in this case: `:map cw dwi` is not repeatable with `.` as a single action, and `caw` also removes the first character of the word. An option to remove the special case exists in Neovim: https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/6234

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [`:h cw`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#cw):

```
                        *cw* *cW*
Special case: When the cursor is in a word, "cw" and "cW" do not include the
white space after a word, they only change up to the end of the word.  This is
because Vim interprets "cw" as change-word, and a word does not include the
following white space.
```

However rather than using a macro you should go with a substitution command that will be less troubles:

```
%s/\(.\)\w\+\s\+/\1, /

%                        Adapt the range to the lines you want to change
   \(.\)                  Capture the first character to reuse it in the second part with \1
        \w\+              match the following word characters
            \s\+          match the following withespaces
                /\1, /   replace what was matched by the captured character, a comma and a whitespace
```

Comment: Might also do `c/ \S<cr>,` ...which is repeatable.... `j.j.j.j` etc.

Comment: Sure there are a lot of ways, I'd still rather use a subsitution but don't hesitate to post your own answer @BLayer